# Run Facebook Messenger Bot APIv3.1 in dev mode without requiring permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger-bot

I just updated my Facebook Messenger App from API version 2.11 to 3.1. Due to the new required permissions for reqeusting the user's gender, locale, and timezone by the newly introduced permissions `pages_user_gender`, `pages_user_locale`, `pages_user_timezone` it's somehow not possible to run my bot in development mode without getting an error from the Facebook API `{"error":{"message":"(#100) Insufficient permission to access user profile.","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"error_subcode":2018247,"fbtrace_id":"FvMjZnojWfG"}}` when requesting the user's profile information.

Do I miss some setting? Is there a way to run my bot during development without requiring those permissions? Otherwise, development and even a test run with some beta testers before reviewing and releasing the bot would not be possible anymore, which is really annoying.

Answer (score 3):

You may ask for those permissions in the Messenger Tab of the App
[image: permissions image]

Image credit: https://help.upinion.com/facebook-messenger/integration-steps/6-facebook-app-review-part-2-facebook-messenger-integration